# Equivalent of Spivak's Calculus in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

My understanding is that Spivak's Calculus is widely considered the finest textbook in Calculus, a thing of beauty. I like it in that it both teaches Calculus as well as several other important concepts in higher math generally--all through a very finely selected collection of exercises.

Is there an equivalent text on Linear Algebra?

Comment: You might find some relevant suggestions in the many "good linear algebra textbook" questions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra+reference-request?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Comment: If you want a book on linear algebra that puts the material within the context of broader theories, then it's best to pick a book that teaches abstract algebra and linear algebra together. For example, it's good to be able to apply facts about groups, rings (especially polynomial rings) and fields to linear algebra and vice versa. Examples at an introductory level include Artin's *Algebra* and Godement's *Algebra*.

Answer (score 4):

[Linear Algebra Done Right](http://linear.axler.net/), by Sheldon Axler

Comment: Maybe. It's logically lovely, but some think it idiosyncratic. I don't think you can describe Spivak that way.

Comment: Reading the first chapter now--holy crap, this book reads smooth as a Hollywood script! Thank you!

Comment: If you would like to view some new videos that were made to accompany Linear Algebra Done Right, then go to http://www.linear.axler.net/LADRvideos.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would say [finite dimensional vector spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387900934). The underlying reason being primarily the way it is "spoken of" from other math majors. Perhaps an alternative would be Hoffman and Kunze.